LSUS server update client ubuntu 22.04
I want to install a server to perform package updates.
It is similar to a WSUS server on windows.
Please tell me where to start.

Windows Server Update Services is part of the Microsoft Windows Server software and provides (among other things) updates for Microsoft products to Windows clients. How is that different from apt in Ubuntu?

no, That's not what I meant. I have many Ubuntu client. I want to build a private Server which dose the update service pack. It same WSUS on Windows.
